# javascript/jQuery setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

i have this code:

```
$('.myButton').live('click',function(){
    var checkTextValue = setTimeout(function() {
    var textVal = $('p').text();
    if (textVal == 'expectedValue'){
        alert('done');
    } else {
       setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);
    }
    },10);
 });
```

when the button is clicked for the first time it works just fine, but when the button is clicked more than once alert is called n+ times(if i click one more time on the button an alert pops->i click "ok" and then one more alert pops; after this if i click one more time 3 alerts pops); is there any way to remove the function after textVal == 'expectedValue' returns true ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting a `return false;` at the end of that branch of the if statement?

Alternatively, you could simply set a flag such as `hasRun = 1`, and simply check for that value before you run anything inside that branch of the if statement...

Comment: actually this is a simplified version of my script; my original script is a plugin that uploads pictures. so when i click on mu button i want to upload a picture(using an iframe)...and when the picture is loaded...my php file writes "<p>1</p>" in my iframe...so i check with that setTimeout if the file is uploaded or not. so each time when i click on my button i want to upload a picture. So what can i do with that flag?

Answer (score 0):

In the `else` condition you are just setting the time-out...you should also be updating the value of your 'expectedValue'...right?

And `return` the boolean value accordingly for the conditional.

You could use a new boolean flag...or use existing values for the same purpose.
Let me know if you need elaboration.

Comment: pfff...i can;t make it work...can you show me the answer on my code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the timeout (using `clearTimeout`) before calling `setTimeout` to prevent simultaneous executions.

Comment: ...before calling setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setInterval()` to achieve this rather than `setTimeout()`:

```
var intervalId = 0;
$('.myButton').live('click', function(){
    if (intervalId != 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        var textVal = $('p').text();
        if (textVal == 'expectedValue'){
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            intervalId = 0;

            alert('done');
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

Another advantage of this approach is that you can determine if they have already clicked it and mention that this is already being checked.

```
var intervalId = 0;
$('.myButton').live('click', function(){
    if (intervalId != 0) {
        alert('check already in progress... please wait');
        return false;
    }
    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        var textVal = $('p').text();
        if (textVal == 'expectedValue'){
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            intervalId = 0;

            alert('done');
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

Alternatively you could prompt them and ask the user if they would like to stop the checking (in this case simply clear the interval and set intervalId to 0).